# Portsip Ambiguous use of subscript(_:) Error

Tags: ios, swift, portsip

I am using NSMutableArray in one of the class that time working as expected. But now I am trying to implement third party framework (Portsip) in my application. I got below Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)' error.

Please help me on this and Thanks in Advance.

```
var assessmentQuestionArray:NSMutableArray!

(((assessmentQuestionArray.object(at: selectedSection) as AnyObject)["child"] as AnyObject)[selectedRow] as AnyObject).setValue(selectedLang, forKey: "answer") ----  Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'
```

Comment: Why use NSMutableArray at all instead of a native swift array? What about breaking up that very long statement into several shorter statements to better under where the issue is.

Comment: Get rid of the `NSMutableArray` and `AnyObject` where possible, and use `Array` and `as? TheObjectsRealType` instead.